# how to conect with roscore in docker?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As titles, how can I running a roscore in docker with ROS_MASTER_URI=XX.X.X.X. And make the nodes outside docker can connect with the docker roscore using specified ROS_MASTER_URI?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329316/how-to-conect-with-roscore-in-docker?/) by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you misunderstood the role of the environment variable `ROS_MASTER_URI`.
If you have the ROS MASTER and a ROS NODE, the variable will be used by the ROS NODE to know where to look for the MASTER. It's not setting the master URI to a specific value.

In your example, you should just run `roscore` in the Docker, without setting any environment variable.
`roscore` will print to screen the URI where the master can be reached.

In the terminal where you want to run your nodes, you will have to run `export ROS_MASTER_URI=XX.X.X.X` with the URI that has been previously printed.

Moreover, if using Docker, you should make sure that the Docker container has not been run in isolated mode.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-10-13**:
I have not been able to get this to work.  I am using a Docker within WSL 2.  I run the docker with the command:

```
docker run -it --network=host ros:noetic-ros-base
```

Then typing: `hostname -I`, I get two IP addresses:

```
192.168.65.3 172.17.0.1
```

Then I do `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.65.3:11311`, and run `roscore` in the docker, and am unable to see it from outside the docker.  Similarly if I use the other IP address.

I have not been able to find any way to make roscore visible outside the docker